# Range comparison in ObjC / iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, resultset

In my app, I have a different grading levels

e.g.

```
70-80 Good
81-95 Excellent
60    Average
```

Then I have a test result value like 77 or 88.

**Attention:** I save range in database like 70-80 as Text.

How can I compare this values from grading level to get appropriate answer?

Comment: Greading?  What is that?

Comment: Do you mean "grading", as in the result of an academic test?

Comment: yes. Grading as the result of academic Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read from Database or coredata or textfile into a string.

Let you read the string as :

```
NSString *gradeRange=@"70-80";
NSArray *breakRange=[gradeRange componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

NSInteger score=77;

if( (score > [breakRange[0] integerValue]) && (score < [breakRange[0] integerValue]) ){
     NSLog(@"%ld lies in %@.", score, gradeRange);
     //Here you can log, display as per your need
}
//else if // similarly for all ranges
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
NSString* str_good = @"70-80"; //From the database
NSRange good_range = NSRangeFromString(str_good);
good_range.length = good_range.length-good_range.location; //Ranges are (location, length) we convert it to that format

NSString* str_excellent = @"81-95"; //From the database
NSRange excellent_range = NSRangeFromString(str_excellent);
excellent_range.length = excellent_range.length-excellent_range.location; //Ranges are (location, length) we convert it to that format

int grading = 77;


if(NSLocationInRange(grading, good_range)) {
    NSLog(@"good");
}
if(NSLocationInRange(grading, excellent_range)) {
    NSLog(@"excellent");
}
```

Comment: Yes, It's Working But for my textfield how can i restrict user to put input with this format only?

Comment: and my Range may be a single value also. Like user can give input 70-80 good or 85 Best

Comment: It also not comparing the end values of the range.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store the range as text in the database. That way you have to parse it every time you read it and split it into the upper and lower bounds for that grade level.

Instead, store the levels in table like this:

```
Name      | minimumScore | maximumScore
Excellent | 81           | 95
Good      | 70           | 80
```

That way you can easily query for the level's name by using a `WHERE` clause like `actual >= minimumScore AND actual <= maximumScore`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you can do like:

```
if (result >= 81 && result <= 95) {
    //Excellent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one custom method as per your grades some what like this,

```
-(NSString*)getGradeWithMin:(int)minValue max:(int)maxValue
{
    return (minValue>80 && maxValue<=100) ? @"A" : ((minValue>60 && maxValue<=80) ? @"B" : ((minValue>40 && maxValue<=60) ? @"C" : @"D"));
}
```

After this Make use of `componentsSeparatedByString` to separate your max and min range.

```
NSArray *boundary = [@"70-80" componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSLog(@"Grade is : %@",[self getGradeWithMin:[[boundary objectAtIndex:0] intValue] max:[[boundary objectAtIndex:1] intValue]]);
```

Hope this can give you idea.

Comment: yikes, you should really fix your typos as well as the incorrect used capitals and uncommon method naming towards something like `- (NSString *)getGradeWithMin:(int)minValue max:(int)maxValue`